# Plot unit step using if else conditions

Tags: matlab

i am using this code to plot unit step function

```
t1=-2:0.01:2;

if t1>=0
    y=1;
else if t1<0
    y=0;

   end

end

subplot(3,1,1)
plot(t1,y)`
```

but i dont get the desired output.It is plotting zero for y at every point.

Comment: FYI, that `else if` should probably be `elseif` - then you can remove the extra `end`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code tests all t1 values at once and is the same as

```
if all(t1>=0)
    y=1;
else if all(t1<0)
    y=0;

   end

end
```

What you want is:

```
t1=-2:0.01:2;
y = zeros(size(t1));
y(t1>=0) = 1;

subplot(3,1,1)
plot(t1,y)
```

Another (less efficient) way of doing this is:

```
t1=-2:0.01:2;
for index=1:length(t1)
    if t1(index)>=0
        y(index)=1;
    else if t1(index)<0
            y(index)=0;
        end
    end
end

subplot(3,1,1)
plot(t1,y)
```

As P0W indicates, there is also the heaviside function which generates step outputs similar to yours (although with the value 0.5 at 0). However, the heaviside function is only available if you have the symbolic toolbox installed.

Comment: You forgot the `heaviside`